# unit test did not respond as expected

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation, castle-dynamicproxy

I am using Validationaspect in my project,
I have fluentvalidation rules, these are simple rules, like not accepting a field blank.
validation works in debugger mode,throws fluentvalidation.validationexception

Everything worked correctly in debugger mode!!!

```
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
    public class ValidationAspect:MethodInterception
        {
            Type _validatorType;
            public ValidationAspect(Type validatorType)
            {
                if(!typeof(IValidator).IsAssignableFrom(validatorType))
                {
                    //farkli validator yollandı 
                    throw new System.Exception(AspectMessages.WrongValidationType);
                }
    
                _validatorType = validatorType;
            }
            protected override void OnBefore(IInvocation invocation)
            {
    
                var validator = (IValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(_validatorType);
                var entityType = _validatorType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                var entities = invocation.Arguments.Where(t => t.GetType() == entityType);
                foreach (var entity in entities)
                {
                    ValidationTool.Validate(validator,entity);
                }
            }
        }
    
     public static class ValidationTool
    {
        public static void Validate(IValidator validator, object entity)
        {
            var context = new ValidationContext<object>(entity);
            var result = validator.Validate(context);
            if (result.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                throw new ValidationException(result.Errors);
            }
        }
    }
```

Why doesn't test method throw validationexception, method works?

```
[TestClass]
    public class PersonManagerTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ValidationException))]
        public void product_add_validation_check()
        {
            Mock<IPersonDal> mock = new Mock<IPersonDal>();
            PersonManager productManager = new PersonManager(mock.Object);

            productManager.AddPerson(new Person());
        }
    }



 [ValidationAspect(typeof(PersonValidation), Priority =0)]
    //[CacheRemoveAspect(pattern: "*IPersonService*",Priority =2)]
    public IResult AddPerson(Person person)
    {
        IResult result = BusinessRules.Run(
            CheckIfPersonFullNameExists(person.PersonFirstName, person.PersonLastName));
        if (result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }
        _personDal.Add(person);
        return new SuccessResult(Messages.PersonAddedSuccess);
    }



    public abstract class MethodInterception : MethodInterceptionBaseAttribute
{
    protected virtual void OnBefore(IInvocation invocation) { }
    protected virtual void OnAfter(IInvocation invocation) { }
    protected virtual void OnException(IInvocation invocation, System.Exception e) { }
    protected virtual void OnSuccess(IInvocation invocation) { }
    public override void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var isSuccess = true;
        OnBefore(invocation);
        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            isSuccess = false;
            OnException(invocation, e);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (isSuccess)
            {
                OnSuccess(invocation);
            }
        }
        OnAfter(invocation);
    }
}

  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class|AttributeTargets.Method,AllowMultiple =true,Inherited =true)]
    public abstract class MethodInterceptionBaseAttribute:Attribute,IInterceptor
    {
        public int Priority { get; set; }

        public virtual void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
          
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `MethodInterception`? This isn't a DynamicProxy type. Your should provide a complete and clearer example for someone to help you. I don't see where you are expecting DynamicProxy to jump in, you've not added any interceptors in the provided code.

Comment: Hi Rossi,

I edited you can review.
thanks for your answer

Comment: Okay, so `ValidationAspect` is an `IInterceptor`, however that isn't how you use interceptors with DynamicProxy, I recommend reading the docs. I'm also surprised you are trying to use FluentValidation like this, you'd normally define a class inheriting from `AbstractValidator<Person>` which is auto-discovered, rather than messing with something like DynamicProxy.

Comment: I do not know much, I learned from udemy lessons.

It works in debugger mode but not in my test project, I will continue to investigate why.


thank you for your answer

Comment: "It works in debugger mode but not in my test project", if you meant works in your unit test but not your test program, that might be because Moq is built using DynamicProxy so could be working different. However, I'd still recommend using FluentValidation with normal C# code rather than generating proxies, readability will be better as will performance.